# Why does this list return empty whilst trying to scrape links from a section of this website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to see if the first link under the header 'Investor Reports' has changed from this website: https://www.thameswater.co.uk/about-us/investors/debt-information
But when I try to return the list of urls in the specific section of the website it comes back empty. I read this may be because the website updates using Java and BeautifulSoup can't read Java??

Here's my code:

```
# Importing libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import schedule
import time

# setting up the URL
URL = 'https://www.thameswater.co.uk/about-us/investors/debt-information'

# perform get request to the url
reqs = requests.get(URL)

# extract all the text that you received from
# the GET request
content = reqs.text

# convert the text to a beautiful soup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

# Empty list to store the output
urls = []

# For loop that iterates over all the <li> tags
for h in soup.find('div', {'class': 'tw-download-list'}):

    # looking for anchor tag inside the <li>tag
    a = h.find('a')
    try:
    
       # looking for href inside anchor tag
       if 'href' in a.attrs:
        
           # storing the value of href in a separate variable
           url = a.get('href')
        
           # appending the url to the output list
           urls.append(url)
        
     # if the list does not has a anchor tag or an anchor tag
     # does not has a href params we pass
     except:
        pass

# print all the urls stored in the urls list
list(urls)
```

Please let me know if this is an issue with my code or if it is a problem with BeautfiulSoup and Java

**Edit**: I've now added the headers which did help however when I use the following code I still receive an empty list:

```
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
# setting up the URL
URL = 'https://www.thameswater.co.uk/about-us/investors/debt-information'

# perform get request to the url
reqs = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

# extract all the text that you received from
# the GET request
content = reqs.text

# convert the text to a beautiful soup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

# Empty list to store the output
urls = []

# For loop that iterates over all the <li> tags
for h in soup.findAll('div', {'id': 'accordion__panel-raa-379748'}, {'class': 'accordion__panel'}):

    # looking for anchor tag inside the <li>tag
    a = h.findAll('a')
    try:
        
        # looking for href inside anchor tag
        if 'href' in a.attrs:
            
            # storing the value of href in a separate variable
            url = a.get('href')
            
            # appending the url to the output list
            urls.append(url)
            
    # if the list does not has a anchor tag or an anchor tag
    # does not has a href params we pass
    except:
        pass

    # print all the urls stored in the urls list
list(urls)
```

The part of the html I want is all the links under:

```
<div data-accordion-component="AccordionItemPanel" class="accordion__panel" aria-hidden="false" id="accordion__panel-raa-379748">
```

**Edit 2:** Images of element id:
[image: Element]

[image: stacktrace of element]

Comment: The headers helped but I'm still receiving an empty list as mentioned in the edit so I didn't want to post a new question on the same topic.

Comment: There is no element with id `accordion__panel-raa-379748` in page. That number at the end - 3797... will change everythime you load the page, it's dynamic. What exact link are you trying to scrape?

Comment: I am trying to scrape all the links under Investor Relations but none others on the page. I think there is an element with that id and when I refreshed the page, its number didn't change. Each heading has an element with a similar id with the last digit changing only due to the order on the page. I will edit the question to include a screenshot of the id.

Comment: There is no 'Investor relations'. Do you mean 'Investor reports'?

Comment: Yes Investor Reports, my bad

Comment: Yes.. There are a couple of 'Investor reports' accordions on that page. And that *is* a dynamic number, it changes either on refresh, either on reopening the page, etc. Are you interested in both accordion links?

Comment: Ok, apologies. I'm only interested in the investor reports under 'Thames Water Utilities Limited' i.e the first set of investor report links.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give requests a headers, otherwise website will refuse access. The following code will access the website (and you can adapt it to run on schedule, like you were taught a couple of questions ago):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import schedule
import time
import re

headers= {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get('https://www.thameswater.co.uk/about-us/investors/debt-information', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
for a in soup.select('a'):
    print(a.get_text(strip=True), a['href'])
```

Response printed in terminal:

```
[...]
Investor briefing materials consent proposals 5 June 2018.pdf|2.1 MB https://www.thameswater.co.uk/media-library/home/about-us/investors/debt-investors/investor-briefing-materials-consent-proposals-5-june-2018.pdf
Supplementary prospectus 2022.pdf|41 KB https://www.thameswater.co.uk/media-library/home/about-us/investors/debt-investors/thames-water-utilities/thames-water-utilities-finance/prospectus/thames-water-utilities-finance-prospectus-supplement-2022.pdf
Prospectus 2021.pdf|2.4 MB https://www.thameswater.co.uk/media-library/home/about-us/investors/debt-investors/thames-water-utilities/thames-water-utilities-finance/prospectus/prospectus-2021.pdf
[...]
```

And one more thing: `Javascript` and `Java` are 2 entirely different things: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_javascript.html

Update: to locate the urls for the first 'Investor relations' urls, you can use something like this (don't forget to `import re`):

```
for elem in soup.find(string=re.compile("Thames Water Utilities Limited")).find_next('div').find_all('div', string=re.compile("Investor report")):
    print(elem.find_previous('a').get('href'))
```

Which would print out in terminal:

```
https://www.thameswater.co.uk/media-library/home/about-us/investors/debt-investors/thames-water-utilities/thames-water-utilities-finance/reports/annual-report-2017-18.pdf
https://www.thameswater.co.uk/media-library/home/about-us/investors/debt-investors/thames-water-utilities/thames-water-utilities-finance/reports/annual-report-2017-18.pdf
https://www.thameswater.co.uk/media-library/home/about-us/investors/debt-investors/thames-water-utilities/thames-water-utilities/Investors-reports/investor-report-september-2021.pdf
https://www.thameswater.co.uk/media-library/home/about-us/investors/debt-investors/thames-water-utilities/thames-water-utilities/Investors-reports/investor-report-31-mar-2021.pdf
https://www.thameswater.co.uk/media-library/home/about-us/investors/debt-investors/thames-water-utilities/thames-water-utilities/Investors-reports/investor-report-30-sept-2020.pdf
https://www.thameswater.co.uk/media-library/home/about-us/investors/debt-investors/thames-water-utilities/thames-water-utilities/Investors-reports/investor-report-31-march-2020.pdf
https://www.thameswater.co.uk/media-library/home/about-us/investors/debt-investors/thames-water-utilities/thames-water-utilities/Investors-reports/investor-report-30-sep-2019.pdf
https://www.thameswater.co.uk/media-library/home/about-us/investors/debt-investors/thames-water-utilities/thames-water-utilities/Investors-reports/investor-report-31-march-2019.pdf
https://www.thameswater.co.uk/media-library/home/about-us/investors/debt-investors/thames-water-utilities/thames-water-utilities/Investors-reports/investor-report-30-september-2018.pdf
https://www.thameswater.co.uk/media-library/home/about-us/investors/debt-investors/thames-water-utilities/thames-water-utilities/Investors-reports/investor-report-31-march-2018.pdf
```

Documentation for BeautifulSoup can be found at:

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/